# How do we attach a hover event to a fabric DetailsList in an SPFX webpart?

Tags: spfx-webparts, fabric

How do we attach a hover event to a fabric DetailsList in an SPFX web part?

I have a list of documents in a spfx web part displayed in a fabric DetailsList.

When a user hovers over an item I want to display the document using a fabric callout with an iframe pointing to the documents 'WOPI' Url, similar to the way that SharePoint search results do when you hover over a document.

Comment: is ``addEventListener`` failing on those DOM elements?

Comment: no, the question is more about how to get to the element and add the listener using the library.

Comment: I haven't seen the internals of the DetailsList, others like the ChoiceFieldGroup trigger a custom global event, but those are clicks, not mouseovers. And when you search the GitHub code there is nothing hover/mouseover to be found (at first sight) So I fear there are no mouseover hooks and you just have to go in, get the element and use vanilla JS to attach an event

Comment: yeah, i guess i could add some code in componentdidmount to find the elements and attach listeners.  that sucks. i don't need it that bad.

Answer (score 4):

I posted this question on the `office-ui-fabric-react` board a few days ago and DZearing got back to me within a few hours of my asking the question.

his response can be found at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/1847.  He recommended adding the following `onRenderRow` :

```
onRenderRow={ (props, defaultRender) => <div onMouseEnter={ () => console.log('hovering over: ' + props.item.title)}>{defaultRender(props)}</div> }
```

I did not know that the `onRenderRow` method got passed the default renderer.

So I created my details list like this:

```
<DetailsList
                layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns}
                items={this.state.documents}
                onRenderRow={(props, defaultRender) => this.renderDocumentRow(props, defaultRender)}
                setKey="id"
                selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
                columns={[
                  { key: "Edit", onRender: this.rendeDocumentAsLink, name: "", fieldName: "Title", minWidth: 20, },
                  { key: "title", name: "Request #", fieldName: "title", minWidth: 80, },

                ]}
              />
```

In the `renderDocumentRow` method, I wrapped the entire row withini a `div` that has  `mouseenter` and `mouserout` events:

```
 public renderDocumentRow(props,defaultRender): JSX.Element {

    return (
      <div
        onMouseEnter={(event) => this.documentRowMouseEnter(props.item, event)}
        onMouseOut={(evemt) => this.documentRowMouseOut(props.item, event)}
      >
        {defaultRender(props)}
      </div>);
  }
```

The `mousein` and `moouseout` methods get the `wopiframeurl` for the document hovered over, and set some state variables so that I can render an iframe with the wpoisource:

```
public documentRowMouseEnter(trdocument: TRDocument, e: any) {
//mode passed to fetchDocumentWopiFrameURL: 0: view, 1: edit, 2: mobileView, 3: interactivePreview
    this.props.fetchDocumentWopiFrameURL(trdocument.id, 3).then(url => {
      if (!url || url === "") {
        url = trdocument.serverRalativeUrl;
      }
      this.state.documentCalloutIframeUrl=url;
      this.state.documentCalloutTarget = e.target;
      this.state.documentCalloutVisible = true;
      this.setState(this.state);

    });
  }
  public documentRowMouseOut(item: TRDocument, e: any) {

    this.state.documentCalloutTarget = null;
    this.state.documentCalloutVisible = false;
    this.setState(this.state);
    console.log("mouse exit for " + item.title);
  }
```

The render method has the list of documents in a left aligned div, and an iframe in a right aligned div . As a user hovers over a row on the left, a preview of the document is displayed on the right:

```
  <tabs.TabPanel>
        <div style={{ float: "left" }}> 
          <DetailsList
            layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns}
            items={this.state.documents}
            onRenderRow={(props, defaultRender) => this.renderDocumentRow(props, defaultRender)}
            setKey="id"
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
            columns={[
              { key: "Edit", onRender: this.rendeDocumentAsLink, name: "", fieldName: "Title", minWidth: 20, },
              { key: "title", name: "Request #", fieldName: "title", minWidth: 80, },

            ]}
          />
          <input type='file' id='uploadfile' onChange={e => { debugger; this.uploadFile(e) }} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
        <DocumentIframe src={this.state.documentCalloutIframeUrl} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ clear: "both" }}></div>


      </tabs.TabPanel>
```

The display looks like this as I hover over the Office Brand Guidelines file on the left:[image]

It's a little slow to load the document images as I hover over the different documents(especially for larger documents), but it works great, is visually appealing and provides value to the users.